# Formatando input

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Olá, estou com um grande problema em javascript. Preciso de um campo input que seja formatado da seguinte forma:

- Aceite apenas número e pontos;
- Aceite apenas um ponto;
- Após o ponto só aceite 8 casas decimais;

a parte de aceitar apenas número e  apenas um ponto consegui perfeitamente, mas estou quebrando a cabeça com as casas decimais.

segue fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mhk8a4yo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode tentar algo como a adição de mais uma validação. Não é a melhor resposta, mas creio que resolverá:

```
$('#campo').keypress(function(event) {
    if (((event.which != 46 || (event.which == 46 && $(this).val() == '')) ||
            $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && 
            (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) ||
            $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1 && 
            $(this).val().split('.')[1].length >= 8) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}).on('paste', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: É funciona porém, há um problema no navegador firefox onde a tecla backspace para de funcionar, provavelmente algo relacionado ao event.which.. mas obrigado!

Comment: Olá, por nada. Se utilizou o código, por favor selecione a reposta como a resposta correta para sua pergunta. Obrigado.